# SSIS copy multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I have more than 200 MSSQL tables, and want to transfer data to Azure Data Lake Storage.
One approach I consider is to use SSIS with dynamic data flows, i.e create table name variable and do foreach loop over table names and for each table run dataflow. However this approach seems wrong ,though files are created in Data Lake storage with correct schemes data is not transferred due to wrong mappings.
Is there any generic way to create one dynamic data flow and transfer huge number of table's  data?

Comment: Adding azure-data-factory tag to see if ADF can help.

Comment: Add metadata for each table in a metadatabase. Create automatically stored procedures which handles the transfer. And then execute it paralelle in an SQL job agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario you are describing can now be achieved in ADF V2 - V2 added a set of rich control flow enhancements including the lookup activity, parameter passing, and foreach looping.  You can see a tutorial of how to accomplish this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-bulk-copy